# Create android button with tap outer glow animation

Tags: android, xml, button, view, android-custom-view

I searched into through all the internet but did not find an answer how to achieve what I want.

I want to create GlowButton (I mean that it will be button extended) class which is button with outer glow when on pressed or focused state.
See the picture below to understand what I mean:

[image]

This outer glow should appear and disapper with animation (just change opacity).

1. **Simple question.** How can I do this button without animation. I know that I can create something like this:

   ```
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
       <shape>
           <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
           <stroke
               android:width="4dp"
               android:color="@color/orange" />
           <corners
               android:radius="8dp" />
           <padding android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   ...
   ```

   But there is a solid glow. I need gradient glow as on the picture above.
2. **Hard question.** How can I do this button with appear and disappear animation? User touch button — glow appears from 0% opacity to 100% opacity within 300ms. The glow should disappear in a similar way when user stop touching button.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> You can set alpha animation on click of the
>   button. You have to put glow as background to button and when you
>   press the button the background of button will animate like alpha
>   animation with repeate count 1 so it looks like shadow is appear and
>   dissappear. Set animation time 300ms
>
> alpha_animation.xml in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

Layout file is like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGlowBg"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_glow"
        android:padding="20dp"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPinButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="10"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Activity Code

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnGlowBg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_test);

        btnGlowBg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGlowBg);
        btnGlowBg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.btnPinButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                
                btnGlowBg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final Animation startAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha_animation);
                btnGlowBg.startAnimation(startAnimation);


            }
        });
    }
}
```